# Copy files from remote git to Jenkins workspace

Tags: git, jenkins

I have to overwrite some files from remote git repository in Jenkins workspace. What is best way to do it? . Does it have to be done using git commands only?

Comment: is it the same repository as the one cloned by jenkins or a different one?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to download some files from a remote repository without cloning the entire repo? There are multiple options.

**Option 01: Through Raw Link**

If the repo is public you can get the raw link of the file and download it. The raw link is something like below.

`https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/product-apim/master/README.md`

If it's a private repo you can generate an Access token and then append it to the raw link and download.

`https://TOKEN@raw.githubusercontent.com/wso2/product-apim/master/README.md`

**Option 02: Through Github API**

You can consider using GitHub [APIs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) as well.

`curl -H "Authorization: token ${TOKEN}" -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" https://api.github.com/repos/{user}/{repo}/contents/{path}`

**Option 03: Git commands**

You can also use git or [Gitcli](https://cli.github.com/) as well.